# EXPORT_SYMTAB in 2.6 kernels

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Noticed in our makefiles `EXPORT_SYMTAB` is used as described in [here](http://people.netfilter.org/rusty/unreliable-guides/kernel-hacking/sym-exportsymtab.html).

Is it still relevant to 2.6 and above kernels?
I can not find reference what it's current status, but can't find it in LXR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EXPORT_SYMTAB` name per se seems to be gone once and for all since 2.6 kernels. However, the related macro `EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS` seems to have still a small relevance for what concerns SPARC architectures as explained [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/sparclinux/msg05715.html). Quoting directly from the mailing list:

> > >   given that EXPORT_SYMTAB was removed from the kernel tree quite some
> >     > time back, is this related macro still doing anything useful?  just
> >     > asking.
>
> It's only used by sparc so that it can export symbols like `memcpy()`,
>   `memset()` et al. properly
>
> Without this `ifdef` protection while building ksyms.c, string*.h will
>   define these functions as macros, and that makes things like:
>
> ```
> EXPORT_SYMBOL(memcpy)
> ```
>
> and similar not work because `memcpy` will macro expand and thus break
>   the build with syntax errors.

`EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS` macros are still present in 3.4.9 kernel.

```
#> find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec grep -inH EXPORT_SYMTAB {} \;
./arch/sparc/lib/ksyms.c:6:#define EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS
./arch/sparc/include/asm/string_64.h:18:#ifndef EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS
./arch/sparc/include/asm/string_64.h:58:#endif /* !EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS */
./arch/sparc/include/asm/string_32.h:20:#ifndef EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS
./arch/sparc/include/asm/string_32.h:127:#endif /* !EXPORT_SYMTAB_STROPS */
```

Answer (score 2):

Could not find any direct reference. Found following commits in 2.6 kernel though..

```
commit fe4f699c6fb886a8deaf1120fd52402c3bd7c459
Author: Robert P. J. Day <rpjday@crashcourse.ca>
Date:   Sun Jul 5 05:19:29 2009 -0400

    Staging: vt6655: Remove Makefile refs to EXPORT_SYMTAB

    Given that EXPORT_SYMTAB was removed long ago, remove the Makefile
    references to it.

    Signed-off-by: Robert P. J. Day <rpjday@crashcourse.ca>
    Signed-off-by: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@suse.de>


commit 1fad810473423bbf0626fab2fbeb27a4663fa2d5
Author: Adrian Bunk <bunk@stusta.de>
Date:   Sat Jul 30 12:49:56 2005 -0700

    [PATCH] hostap update

    EXPORT_SYMTAB does nothing. There's no need to define something if it
    doesn't have any effect.

    Signed-off-by: Adrian Bunk <bunk@stusta.de>
    Signed-off-by: Jouni Malinen <jkmaline@cc.hut.fi>
    Signed-off-by: Jeff Garzik <jgarzik@pobox.com>
```

This points that EXPORT_SYMTAB is not used anymore.